# Excel VBA Print w Automated File Name and Location using Range.ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: excel, vba, printing

https://www.contextures.com/excelvbapdf.html
**The following is perfect, but it prints the entire sheet.**

full thread

```
  Sub PDFActiveSheet()
'www.contextures.com
'for Excel 2010 and later
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for savng file
strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile

'use can enter name and
' select folder for file
myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
If myFile <> "False" Then
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & myFile
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

**but I'm having trouble with this**

```
'export to PDF if a folder was selected
    If myFile <> "False" Then
  ` wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat 
        Type:=xlTypePDF, 
        Filename:=myFile, 
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, 
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, 
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, 
        OpenAfterPublish:=False`
```

**The only thing I'm trying to accomplish is print a range (Preferably named) in lieu of the entire sheet.  I created dims and set a range to use in lieu of the 'wsA' Sheet and it is bugging.**

```
Dim rnG As Range
Set rnG = Range("Y1:AG46")
rnG.ExportAsFixedFormat _
```

**Are the only lines that I've added. It'll work as I want it, but intermittently and I've got no idea why. It bugs in yellow the entire ExportFileAsFixedFormat subtext and points to not recognizing the specified Range.**

Comment: Please try not use bold face in your entire post: it makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you are not qualifying the range. Try

```
Set rnG = wsA.Range("Y1:AG46")
```

Without qualification works correctly only if `wsA` is the active sheet.

Comment: this format is really confusing the Ctrl+K is no longer working. I did as you said and the same yellow is occurring.                                                                                                     
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim rnG As Range                                                                                                                                 Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet 
Set rnG = wsA.Range("Y1:AG46")

Comment: rnG.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

Comment: the yellow arrow is pointing to the last line: OpenAfterPublish:=False  Is there more info its looking for or is the command not closed properly?